Plastic guides in Shimano brake levers
I have a set of Shimano BL-M6100 brake levers that both are damaged in the plastic guides that guide the piston part from the lever to the actual brake piston. See marked items in photo below.

Is there any way of finding these parts as spares?
I also have a broken 6000 series brake lever from Shimano, but those plastic guides are not the same so it seems they are different at least between different Deore models/years?

Given they both failed, you might choose a different model and hope the cause is resolved in later versions.

know anyone with a 3d printer?

@Criggie BL-M6100 is at the time of writing the latest version (and the next iteration of M6000). I'd also consider that Deore is often considered the most "sturdiest" range (after that, compromises are start being made to save weight), but indeed, if levers keep being broken, searching for alternatives may indeed be a good idea.

@Rеnаud I would consider Deore fairly budget-oriented now. The build&material quality is not so good as eg SLX.  The asker should note that any shimano lever is a suitable replacement, it needn't be another Deore, it could be from a higher (or lower) group.

Both levers failed as result of crashes, so for function the Deore series seems OK by my standards.

Oh, I see that the attached image seems crashed. Will fix that...

As I understand it, Shimano publishes exploded view of their components, that list the different parts of a component, and give the reference number of the spare parts you can get. But there's always a "core" that is considered to be "unitary", and that must be replaced "entirely" if a sub-part brakes. In the case of the BL-M6100 brake levers, however, it's straightforward: only the screws, o-rings and caps can be procured separately.
So there's no official way of getting these parts. Unofficially, you can probably try to salvage the parts from broken levers. But given the relatively low price of BL-M6100 levers (you can get them at 27€ from official European online retailers) and the importance of good working brakes, a replacement is the option I'd recommend.


Firstly, as Renaud mentions in a comment, you should really reconsider the safety aspect of fixing broken brake components (presumably caused by crash damage). Also, from what I could find online, BL-M6100 is only $50 CAD, so even disregarding the safety aspect, the time and energy you spend trying to source replacement parts might not be worth it.
If you're determined to fix these levers though, yes the M6000 lever is different from the M6100 (as you've discovered). Shimano tweaked the Servo-Wave leverage curve for the new generation, and so the plastic piston guides are not interchangeable. If you’re looking to cannibalize other broken levers for parts, any of the M6100, M7100, and M8100 levers will contain the pieces you're looking for.
As a side note, one benefit of the XTR series brake levers is that they're entirely metal and do not have that plastic guide piece. You can see the difference in my teardown guide here: How do I rebuild Shimano XTR hydraulic brake levers?. I suppose you could also argue that the plastic piece serves as a sacrificial weak link to prevent more severe damage to the brake lever body in the event of a crash or whatever, but since spare parts are not readily available, I question the utility of this benefit.
Also, as some dumb guy [sic] pointed out, it may be possible to 3D print a replacement. You'd want to use a durable filament such as nylon or ideally polyoxymethylene (also known as Delrin or acetal), which is likely what the original part is made of. Do keep in mind that if it breaks the brake will probably stop working, so you'd want to be extremely confident in the print quality. Pursuing this (well, really any) repair option would be entirely at your own risk.
Edit: after doing some research, it turns out that 3D printing POM is easier said than done. Looks like the idea of printing the replacements is only really feasible if you use a 3rd party printing service which already has experience working with that stuff. Alternatively, you could get someone to machine some replacements out of billet POM, but at that point it would likely be cheaper just to buy a new brake lever.

I wouldn’t say that the best option is to take the part from other levers: I would consider that levers that have been damaged to such a point should be written off, not repaired. Brakes are among the components for which doing wrong savings can be very costly on a longer term.

@Rеnаud Ah I meant “best given that you’re already determined to try to replace the broken plastic pieces”. I’ll edit to clarify.

Good point, I also edited my answer.

MaplePanda I like both answers from you and @Renauld so I give you a point for stating possible donor models but Renaund seems right to say that there are no way of sourcing spares for this brake lever.

@MagnusK No hard feelings haha, Renaud's answer is pretty comprehensive and I just wanted to add some supplementary information.
